# Choose a specific instance to put an ECS service on

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am creating 3 EC2 instances and then 3 ECS services. I then mount an EFS volume to each EC2 instance and place some data on it. I want to choose which EC2 instance the ECS service gets placed on as the data within each EFS volume is specific to a certain application.

I am attempting to add a type to the EC2 instance which you can see below and then attempting to put the placement constraint on the task ECS service, doing this then stops my EC2 instance from appearing within the console in the ECS cluster.

Is this possible to achieve?

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "huski" {
  count           = var.node_count
  name            = format("huski_%d", count.index)
  desired_count   = 1
  cluster         = var.ecs_cluster_id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.huski[count.index].id
  launch_type     = "EC2"

  placement_constraints {
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:type == ${format("huski_%d", count.index)}"
  }

  network_configuration {
    subnets = var.vpc_private_subnets

    security_groups = [
      var.security_group_id,
    ]
  }

  service_registries {
    registry_arn   = aws_service_discovery_service.main[count.index].arn
    container_name = format("huski_%d", count.index)
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ecs_task_execution_role
  ]
}


resource "aws_instance" "huski" {
  count = var.node_count

  ami = data.aws_ami.ecs.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.huski_ec2.name
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = format("huski_%d", count.index)
  subnet_id = element(var.vpc_public_subnets, 0)

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.huski.id]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    prevent_destroy = false
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_key_pair.generated_key
  ]

  user_data = join("\n",
  [
    "#!/bin/bash\necho ECS_CLUSTER=${var.ecs_cluster_name}\nECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"type\": \"${format("huski_%d", count.index)}\"} > /etc/ecs/ecs.config",
    data.template_file.script[count.index].rendered
  ])

  provisioner "file" {
    source = format("nodes/node_%d", count.index)
    destination = "/var/tmp"

    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ec2-user"
      private_key = tls_private_key.huski[count.index].private_key_pem
      host = self.public_ip
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name = format("%d-huski-terraform", count.index)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not  mount the EFS volumes directly in the ECS tasks, instead of going through the EC2 mounts? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html

Comment: +1 to what @MarkB suggested. [Here is a series of blog posts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) that walks you through how to achieve that scenario (and why it's better).